# Updating deprecated each function when it contains three variables after list

Tags: php, each

I've read a bunch of questions related to `each()` on SO, but not seen one with more than two variables after `(list(`

I'm trying to figure out how to update the following code to be compliant with PHP 7.4

```
if ($show_currencies == true) {
  if (isset($currencies) && is_object($currencies)) {

    reset($currencies->currencies);
    $currencies_array = array();
    print_r($currencies);
    while (list($key, $value, $title) = each($currencies->currencies)) {
        
        $currencies_array[] = array('id' => $key, 'text' => (zen_not_null($value['symbol_left']) ? $value['symbol_left'] : $value['symbol_right']), 'title' => (zen_not_null($value['title']) ? $value['title'] : ''));
    }

    $hidden_get_variables = '';
    reset($_GET);
    while (list($key, $value, $title) = each($_GET)) {
        if ($key != '' && $value != '' && $title != '') {
            if (($key != 'currency') && ($key != zen_session_name()) && ($key != 'x') && ($key != 'y')) {
                $hidden_get_variables .= zen_draw_hidden_field($key, $value, $title);
            }
        }

    }

    require($template->get_template_dir('tpl_header_currencies.php', DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base, 'common') . '/tpl_header_currencies.php');
  }
}
```

I've done some edits where there are only two variables in the parenthesis after `list`, like this for example

```
while (list($key, $val) = each($language)) {
```

changed to

```
foreach ($language as $key => $val ) {
```

but I'm a bit confused on how to make a similar change when there are more than two vars in question.

To  help clarify the code used, these are the array contents.

```
currencies Object
(
[currencies] => Array
    (
        [USD] => Array
            (
                [title] => US Dollar
                [symbol_left] => $
                [symbol_right] => 
                [decimal_point] => .
                [thousands_point] => ,
                [decimal_places] => 2
                [value] => 1.000000
            )

        [EUR] => Array
            (
                [title] => Euro
                [symbol_left] => &euro;
                [symbol_right] => 
                [decimal_point] => .
                [thousands_point] => ,
                [decimal_places] => 2
                [value] => 0.773000
            )

        [GBP] => Array
            (
                [title] => GB Pound
                [symbol_left] => &pound;
                [symbol_right] => 
                [decimal_point] => .
                [thousands_point] => ,
                [decimal_places] => 2
                [value] => 0.672600
            )

        [CAD] => Array
            (
                [title] => Canadian Dollar
                [symbol_left] => $
                [symbol_right] => 
                [decimal_point] => .
                [thousands_point] => ,
                [decimal_places] => 2
                [value] => 1.104200
            )

        [AUD] => Array
            (
                [title] => Australian Dollar
                [symbol_left] => $
                [symbol_right] => 
                [decimal_point] => .
                [thousands_point] => ,
                [decimal_places] => 2
                [value] => 1.178900
            )

    )

[observerAliases:base:private] => Array
    (
        [NOTIFIY_ORDER_CART_SUBTOTAL_CALCULATE] => NOTIFY_ORDER_CART_SUBTOTAL_CALCULATE
    )
```

)

Comment: What is `$title`? I can't see anything in the documentation that supports that usage.

Comment: I think that code is simply wrong. Nothing gets assigned to `$title`, but it never uses the variable either.

Comment: @Barmar I've updated the question with the full code block and the array content

Comment: The array contents are irrelevant.

Comment: The code seems to be expecting it to return elements in the nested array, but that's not how it works.

Comment: `$key` gets a key like `USD`, `GBP`, etc. `$value` gets the corresponding nested array. Nothing is assigned to `$title`.